# Sending notification in 1-to-1 chat to users in tenant

Tags: .net, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm developing a notification bot for my organization in Microsoft Teams, using ASP.NET Core, Graph SDK (from Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraphBeta).
I'm having hard times to develop a simple notification system to specific users in my tenant. Those users are identified by email address.
I already implemented the proactive installation of the app for users and teams, by doing:

The controller that receives a message to send in MS Teams to a specific user

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("notify-approver")]
public async Task<List<string>> NotifyApprover([FromBody] ApproverMessage approverMessage)
{
            var approvers = await _graphServiceClient.Users.Request().Filter($"mail eq '{approverMessage.Email}'").GetAsync();

            var targetApprover = approvers.CurrentPage.ToList().FirstOrDefault();

            var appInstallation= await _graphServiceClient.InstallIfNotAlreadyForUser(targetApprover.Id, _configuration.GetTeamsAppId());


            // PER IL MOMENTO SEMBRA BUG
            var chatId = await _graphServiceClient.GetChatThreadId(targetApprover.Id, appInstallation.Id)

        }
```

The installation works fine and returns a UserScopeTeamsAppInstallation.
This is the function I built for proactive installing:

```
public static async Task<UserScopeTeamsAppInstallation> InstallIfNotAlreadyForUser(this IGraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, string userId, string teamsAppId)
        {
            var appsCollectionPage = await graphServiceClient.Users[userId].Teamwork.InstalledApps.Request().Expand("teamsAppDefinition")
                .GetAsync();
            var appInstallation = appsCollectionPage.CurrentPage.ToList()
                .Find(a => a.TeamsAppDefinition.TeamsAppId.Equals(teamsAppId));

            if (appInstallation != null) return appInstallation;
            var userScopeTeamsAppInstallation = new UserScopeTeamsAppInstallation()
            {
                AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    {"teamsApp@odata.bind", $"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/appCatalogs/teamsApps/{teamsAppId}"}
                }
            };
            var freshInstallation = await graphServiceClient.Users[userId].Teamwork.InstalledApps.Request().AddAsync(userScopeTeamsAppInstallation);
            return freshInstallation;

        }
```

Until now it's ok, but the bad part is in the trial to send proactively a message; as suggested in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages?tabs=csharp) I proceed to get this chatId that should be useful. The funny part is that if I use Graph Client v1.0 I get an internal server error while retrieving this chat object below, then I switched to Beta client and it... kinda works.

```
public static async Task<string> GetChatThreadId(this IGraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, string userId, string teamsAppIdInstallation)
        {
            // forse ci vuole AppInstallationId anziché il semplice teamsAppId della app

            //var chat = await graphServiceClient.Users[userId].Teamwork.InstalledApps[teamsAppIdInstallation].Chat.Request().GetAsync();

            /*
             * Perché dá internal server error?? Possibile bug della API di graph
             * perché viceversa da graph explorer funziona e restituisce l'id della chat
             *
             * Per adesso sono costretto a salvarmi in un database tutte le conversation references.
             */

            var chat =  graphServiceClient.Users[userId].Teamwork.InstalledApps[teamsAppIdInstallation].Chat.Request().GetAsync();


            return chat.Id.ToString();
            //return "CIAONE";
        }
```

[image: Chat object obtained when retrieving in GetChatThreadId function]
From now on I getting more and more confused by the amount of scattered information.
What I saw is that usually the thing should be:

- On the bot callback OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync the ConversationReference should be saved because it is fired when the bot is installed. But then this object is stored in a ConcurrentDictionary and its lifetime is limited to runtime. In my case I should persist it, but I can't find what properties to store and how to recreate the ConversationReference object that in the examples is always stored as it is, but no example with persistence.
- Given the above problem I can't use on the bot adapter the method ContinueConversationAsync.
- In any case, if we look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages?tabs=csharp) even if it explicitly say to retrieve this ChatId it performs the operation by using cached ConversationReference objects.

How am I supposed to do such a "simple" thing like sending a simple message to a person while it looks so much confusing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution I found was to save the ConversationReference object in the OnTeamsMembersAddedAsync callback when the Bot is installed for a user by serializing it in json and saving into a Sqlite database. For retrieving it i deserialize it and use

Answer (score 2):

To retain the conversation reference properties, check storage layer concept in [Bot State Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#:%7E:text=State%20within%20a%20bot%20follows%20the%20same%20paradigms,may%20handle%20any%20given%20turn%20of%20the%20conversation)

You can go ahead and try by placing this code sample in startup.cs file:

```
services.AddSingleton<IStorage>(new AzureBlobStorage(Configuration["_connectionstring"], Configuration["BlobName"]));
services.AddSingleton<UserState>();
services.AddSingleton<ConversationState>();
services.AddSingleton<BotStateService>();
```

And also, please have a look on [proactive-messages](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages) sample code.

Comment: thanks for the reply. In then end I found a "simple" solution without many hassles by saving each ConversationReference object in a local Sqlite db: I serialize it in JSON and then save it as a json string and the when I retrieve it I deserialize it from json string and use it as explained in proactive messaging documentation